# Is there any efficient way to calculate covariance matrix using PyTorch?

Tags: python, performance, pytorch

I want to calculate covariance matrix from vectors `a` and `b`, like `k[i][j] = exp( -(a[i]-b[j])**2 )`.

In numpy, I can write as follows,

```py
import numpy as np

r = np.subtract.outer(a, b)
k = np.exp(-r*r)
```

In PyTorch, I can write naive code, but it's slower than numpy.

```py
import torch

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b)):
        k[i][j] = torch.exp( -(a[i]-b[j])**2 )
```

How should I write efficient code using PyTorch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use broadcasting:

```py
r = a[:, None] - b[None, :]
k = torch.exp(-r**2)
```

Comment: that's a good solution but I think reshape is slightly faster! https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeh5H.png

Comment: @UlisesBussi this is odd, adding a singleton dimension is O(1) operation. is it possible that creating the temp var `r` makes the runtime effect?

Comment: nope, I've tried with an auxiliar r to do be fair... I add this code to my answer if you want. and show results (i'm reviewing to check that's not an human error)

Comment: Solved, you've edited? you used k=np.exp before? that's the problem it's seems that np.exp is slower than torch.exp, now I have almost the same times!

Comment: @UlisesBussi I didn't edit. using `timeit` I see that there's no significant time difference.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the goods of reshape and multipliing ndims arrays:

```
k = torch.exp(- (a.reshape(-1,1)*b.reshape(1,-1))**2)
```

*EDIT*

Also this method is valid with numpy:

```
k = np.exp(- (a.reshape(-1,1)*b.reshape(1,-1))**2)
```

Comment: broadcasting is also valid with numpy. In fact, many slicing/indexing tricks are shared between pytorch and numpy.